# How to convert tensorflow model to TensorRT

Tags: tensorflow, onnx, nvidia-jetson, tensorrt

I am looking for end-to-end tutorial, how to convert my trained tensorflow model to TensorRT to run it on Nvidia Jetson devices. I know how to do it in abstract (.pb -> ONNX - > [Onnx simplifyer] -> TRT engine), but I'd like to see how other do It, because I had no speed gain after converting, maybe i did something wrong. I can't believe that there is no pipeline with steps description in the internet. That's why I am asking here, maybe you have seen such a tutorial...

Comment: Does this help https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/tensorrt/quick-start-guide/index.html. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, right, these instructions describes exactly what I want to do, but wanted more detailed tutorial for newbies. Have already converted the model. After I implement the TRT inference I'll make the tutorial and post It here. Thanks for your reply

Comment: here is the answer. I added the code for inference on video too. https://github.com/pavloshargan/TF-TRT-Pytorch-TRT_tutorial